# How to "Fly" Through Scene

Tags: camera, scene

Is there a way to 'fly' through a scene in Blender with the mouse, like in Unreal Engine? That is, without animating the camera?

Comment: hello, it's called fly walk navigation in Blender

Comment: How do I enter that?

Comment: Edit preferences, go to Navigation, and change View Navigation to Fly

Comment: Okay. Thanks @moonboots!

Comment: And @Marty Fouts! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blender supports two different navigation modes.  To switch between them, edit preferences, go to the *Navigation Tab* where you'll find the ["Fly&Walk"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/walk_fly.html) panel.  select "Fly".

[image: preferences navigation tab showing fly navigation]

Depending on whether you have auto-save enabled for preferences, you may need to press the "Save Preferences" button to make the change permanent.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @BlenderMaster15 you're welcome.